# Out of Bounds Exception in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, indexoutofboundsexception, android-adapter

I have 8 Images in the array list and I have to place only 4 of them in the grid and when I press next the next 4 images are to be displayed in the same grid

I am using the for loop as

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            ItemClassForCategoryImages itemClassForCategoryImages = new MainActivity().new ItemClassForCategoryImages();
            itemClassForCategoryImages.imageId = imgesForCategories[i];
            itemClassForCategoryImages.GridText = GridText[i];
            data.add(itemClassForCategoryImages);
        }
```

and the other for loop as

```
textViewForMoreOption.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                data = new ArrayList<MainActivity.ItemClassForCategoryImages>();
                for (j = i; j < i+4; i++) {
                    ItemClassForCategoryImages itemClassForCategoryImages = new MainActivity().new ItemClassForCategoryImages();
                    itemClassForCategoryImages.imageId = imgesForCategories[j];
                    itemClassForCategoryImages.GridText = GridText[j];
                    data.add(itemClassForCategoryImages);
                    i=0;
                }
                CustomAdapteForGrid adapter = new CustomAdapteForGrid(
                        BaseActivity.width, BaseActivity.height, data, ctx, 2);
                gridViewForCategories.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
```

But this is giving me out of bounds exeption.
Could someone give me an easy method ... ?

Comment: Have you check the Adapter size? As you are adding more button, it shoudl be 9 instead of 8.

Comment: I'm not sure however you cannot create an instance of any activities by your own the context would been missing.

Comment: Where is the second snippet declared? Where do you init `i` (is it decalred final)?? Why do you do `i=0` at each loop? you never increment `j`? Can you post the whole code instead of snippets. It will help in understanding your flow..